# Semi-custom WCF proxy returns zeros, despite valid data coming back on wire

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

There is a series of SOAP services which I wish to call (across a series of services), and while the end points are well defined & documented, there is no WSDL data... so I decided to build my own.
In order to do so, I built a test WCF service which matches the known interface of the service I wish to call.

I then saved the WSDL it exposed, changed the base address the WSDL references, created my proxy (with wsdl.exe), added it to a test client project, and can successfully create a proxy and make calls which causes the SOAP service to send the expected response... only this expected response is not picked up by the proxy and returned to the calling code.

When looking at the back and forth traffic... I can clearly see that the service is replying with what I want.

**Any suggestions as to how I might troubleshoot this and get the proxy to pickup the data?**

Given the replies are effectively identical, I'm forced to look back at the differences between what my client is sending and another sends.

A known working app sends it's XML blob starting with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

While my client immediately starts with the envelope (without the xml tag, and with one less namespace):

`<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`

The other difference is that the message within the body is prefixed by a namespace in theirs, while mine it is not... though both define this namespace within the tag.

Ala:

```
<s:Body>
    <u:DoSomething xmlns:u="urn:http://some.namespace.org" />
</s:Body>
```

VS:

```
<s:Body>
    <DoSomething xmlns="urn:http://some.namespace.org" />
</s:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a namespace:

```
s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
```

It's setting the encoding style for the envelope which, even though it's not required [per the SOAP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-soap12-part1-20030624/#soapencattr), *may* be required by the specific implementation you're talking to. Do you have enough control over what you're sending from the client to get that put on there?

Other than that, the XML PI is not required and I think you're definitely on the right track looking at the body XML. This is almost always the case of some kind of namespace mismatch somewhere. Are you 100% positive the namespace URIs are *identical*?

Comment: Alas I've little experience with WCF, so do not know how much control I would have to inject the encodingStyle into the request, or even document it as part of the generated WSDL file. 

As far as the URIs in the body... yes, the URIs are identical. The sole difference between them is one has/uses a prefix (ie 'xmlns:u=', while mine is not so prefixed (ie 'xmlns=').

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is the VS version using a "default" XML namespace. There are soap parsers that I've worked which don't work correctly when using an un-aliased (default) namespaces. If you know using the u: alias works with the service, your proxy should also generate it even when every tag inside the s:Body element is prefixed with the alias.

Comment: How does/where (does) one do that? The WSDL & proxy already has a namespace associated with it so as to match what the server is expecting.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can get pretty tricky to shape the soap structure in WCF but it is possible. Its certainly an advanced topic that requires understanding of how WCF creates messages. This [MSDN article on MessageContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) has all the information you need to get started. If you're new to WCF, I'd start with one of the books from the O'Reilly publisher to get the basics of WCF down before working with MessageContract.